# Doppler effect in sound

Tags: doppler-effect

In Doppler effect for sound formula we consider the velocity of source and observer w.r.t. medium but just what about velocity of sound it should also be w.r.t medium right? If the medium is moving with some velocity then do we consider the speed of sound in still medium or moving medium.

According to me it should be w.r.t medium as speed of sound depends on wind speed.

Tell if I am right or wrong.

Comment: Yes ... each medium has a different speed of sound.  Also, the speed of sound in air varies with air temperature.

Comment: If the medium is moving with some velocity then do we consider the speed of sound in still medium or moving medium?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer.  Is the medium experiencing laminar flow or turbulent flow?  I can't assume that all parts of the medium are moving with the same velocity.

Comment: Let's take an example: The medium is air, the velocities of observer and source are Vo and Vs respectively, velocity of sound in still air is V and now wind starts blowing with velocity W from source to observer. Now as medium is moving we have to consider velocity of observer and source w.r.t to medium. What about sound? Do we have to consider it's velocity w.r.t to medium in order to calculate the apparent frequency heard by the observer due to Doppler effect?